# How to output a matlab figure to use in Latex?

Tags: matlab, latex, matlab-figure

The font is not compatible with my Latex document when i use ".eps".

Is there a way to export like gnuplot does? Font embedded in ".tex" format?

Comment: I suggest the FEX package `export_fig`, it provides many options.

Comment: Besides [embedding fonts](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35429-eps-utility-toolbox), two other options that come to mind are to [have LaTeX create the image itself](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange?q=pstricks) or to choose a suitable typeface before exporting the figure.

Comment: Using .emf always worked for me. Maybe worth a try.

Comment: can you work with PDF in your LaTeX distro? if so you could set the `PaperPosition` and `papersize` then use `saveas` to output your figure as a `PDF`.  I've started to use `PDF` instead of `EPS` for my vector figures.